# How can I move one schema into another with different fields?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I created an application to replace a legacy one that we had for a while, and I need to move the old database records into the new system, but the schemas are not the same. I'm wondering if there is any way to move the old schema into the new, ignoring the fields that don't exist in the new table, and moving fields that have changed to their updated version.

My old schema is Microsoft SQL Server and has the following fields:

```
[req_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[req_user_id] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[req_subject] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
[req_details] [nvarchar](4000) NOT NULL,
[req_request_date] [date] NOT NULL,
[req_year] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[req_expect_date] [date] NOT NULL,
[leader] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[member1] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[member2] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[member3] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[member4] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[member5] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[member6] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[status_code] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[hours_used] [int] NULL,
[completed_date] [date] NULL,
[category_code] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[staff_comments] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
[response_Email] [bit] NOT NULL,
[response_Phone] [bit] NOT NULL,
[response_Fax] [bit] NOT NULL,
[response_online_upload] [bit] NOT NULL,
[response_post_mail] [bit] NOT NULL,
[response_file] [bit] NOT NULL,
[response_pickup] [bit] NOT NULL,
```

My new schema is MySQL and looks like this:

```
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `details` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `eta` date NOT NULL,
  `leader` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `member1` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `member2` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `member3` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `member4` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `member5` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `member6` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `time_spent` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_completed` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `comments` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `response_method` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
```

Is there any way to do this and salvage our old records in the new system?

Comment: Use the data export tool in sql server? What have you tried?

Comment: I've generated a sql script from sql server, but I'm really hoping to avoid going through it and changing the destination fields by hand.

Comment: How long can it possibly take? There are only around 20 columns here and all the names don't quite match up. I would strongly advise you to normalize your members though. Repeating columns like that is not a good way to handle that kind thing. What happens when you need a 7th member?

Comment: Sure, there are only 20 columns, but doing so manually would involve updating the insert statement for thousands of records.

Comment: Why??? Use the data export tool and do the whole thing in one shot.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what would you use as a destination? A flat file? Excel file? There is no export to MySQL database, nor is there an option to export to sql file from the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard.

Comment: I am not a mysql person but surely there is an import function in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the Data Export tool to generate an xlsx file, then used Navicat to import it as a new table to the database, and then used simple inserts statements to move the data to the other table. I was appalled by the response this question got on SO, but I'm glad I found a solution on my own.